# Show that the universal mapping is not surjective.

Tags: tensor-products

Let $V$ and $W$ be two real vector spaces and let $\psi : V \times W \to V \otimes W$ be the canonical mapping $\psi(v , w) = v \otimes w$. How can I show that $\psi$ is not surjective? Could I take $V = W = \mathbb{R}$ for counterexample?

Comment: You can see a few answers here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1191924/is-it-true-that-every-element-of-v-otimes-w-is-a-simple-tensor-v-otimes-w